# При удаленном запуске docker-compose возникает ошибка с монтированием томов

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Пытаюсь запустить проект на docker-compose через удаленный сервер. Все работает, но как только добавляю пункт про монтирование тома (`volumes`) выдает ошибку:

```sh
Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'C:/Users/user/Projects/my-raspberry-test' mount path must be absolute
```

Для запуска использую инструменты из PhpStorm

[image: Настройка docker в phpstorm]

Сам docker-compose.yml файл выглядит так:

```
version: "3"

services:
  php:
    image: php:cli
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command: php -S 0.0.0.0:80
```

По ssh проверил:

- Daemon запущен,
- Docker работает (на подобном Dockerfile с теми же задачами),
- Docker-compose работает (на этом же файле).

Также проверил удаленный запуск docker с использованием phpstorm и файлом:

```
FROM php:cli
COPY . /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
CMD php -S 0.0.0.0:80
```

Это ошибку не выдало и заработало.

ОС на устройствах:

- ПК: Windows 10
- Сервер: Fedora Server

Без монтирования тома в docker-compose, все запускается. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой?
php для примера.

Comment: у Вас в ошибке явно присутствует виндовый путь: "mount path: 'C:/Users/user/Projects/my-raspberry-test'". Может, дело в этом? ОТкуда он берётся в таком виде?

Comment: Вы монтируете к тому же каталогу, где находится файл доке, попробуйте создать папку на уровень выше `- ./data:/var/www/html/`

Comment: @S.H это путь к проекту

Comment: @ipatev_nn попробовал добавить папку и получилось так
`volumes: - ./app:/var/www/html/`, но ошибка не ушла

Answer (score 0):

Путь должен быть абсолютным для удаленного хоста и сами данные должны быть загружены туда же. То есть нужно загрузить проект на удаленный хост.

Все поправил так:

```yaml
volumes:
  - /home/peter-alexeev/my-test:/var/www/html/
```

Также ответ есть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802943/when-running-docker-compose-remotely-an-error-occurs-with-mounting-volumes.
Там посоветовали еще один вариант решения проблемы